# React RecyclerListView giving error on t.dataProvider.getSize is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to load some data into a recycler list view in react-native but I keep getting the following error:

> t.dataProvider.getSize is not a function

I'm unclear on where to resolve this. I understand that it is related to DataProvider class but where would is the size coming from? Any guidance would be helpful as I'm new to React.  Here is my current code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState,useCallback } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Dimensions, Text, Image, TouchableOpacity, useWindowDimensions, RefreshControl, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { RecyclerListView, DataProvider, LayoutProvider, BaseItemAnimator } from 'recyclerlistview';
const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;
  const DataLoader = () => {
    const [ isLoading, setIsLoading ] = useState(false)
    const [ data, setData ] = useState([])

    const layoutProvider = new LayoutProvider(() => {
      const type = 'NORMAL';
      return type;
    }, (type: any , dim: { width: number; height: number; }) => {
      switch (type) {
        case 'NORMAL': 
          dim.width = SCREEN_WIDTH;
          dim.height = 125;
          break;
        default: 
          dim.width = 0;
          dim.height = 0;
          break;
      }
    });
  

  const rowRenderer = (_type:any,data: any) => {
    console.log('rowrenderer called')
    console.log(_type)
    console.log(data)
    if(data)
    {

    return (
      <View style={styles.cardstyle}>
        <TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={styles.body}>
          {/* <CircularImage /> */}
          <Text style={styles.name}>{data.results.name.title} {data.results.name.first} {data.results.name.last}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.description}>{data.gender}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.description}>{data.phone}</Text>
        </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    
    )
        }
        else
        {
         return  (
           <View>
             <Text>No Data Available</Text>
           </View>
         ) 
        }
  }

 const setData2 = (data) => {
   console.log(data);
     const newdataSource=new DataProvider().cloneWithRows(data);
     return newdataSource;
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
async function fetchData() {
       setIsLoading(true)
      try {
        const fetcher = await window.fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?seed=1&page=1&results=20')
        const response = await fetcher.json()
        console.log(response);
        setData(response)
        setData2(response)
      } catch (error) {
        // Do something with error
      } finally {
        setIsLoading(false)   
      }  
     }
     fetchData()
     fetchData()
    }, [])


    return isLoading ? <div>Loading</div> :   
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <RecyclerListView
        rowRenderer={rowRenderer}
        dataProvider={setData2}
        layoutProvider={layoutProvider}
      />
    </View>
  }

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#E5E5E5',
  },
  cardstyle: {
    width: 366,
    height: 101,
    borderRadius: 12,
    marginLeft: 24,
    marginRight: 24,
    marginTop: 24,
    marginBottom: 24,
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',

  },
  body: {
    left: 81,
  },
  name: {
    top: 18,
    lineHeight: 24,
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontStyle: 'normal',
    color: '#000000',
    
  },
  description: {
    top: 16,
    fontSize: 13,
    lineHeight: 21,
    fontWeight: '500',
    color: 'grey',
    fontStyle: 'normal',
  },
  btnStyl: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    paddingVertical: 4,
    paddingHorizontal:24,
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 165,
    top: 35,
    bottom: 31,
    borderWidth:3,
    borderRadius:100,
    borderColor: '#48A23F',
    height: 32,
    width: 108,
  },
  manage:{
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 14,
    lineHeight: 24,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#48A23F',
  }
});

export default DataLoader
```

Comment: any update on this?